# Json object access

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I am using $.getJSON(url,data,callback) method.

and from url it returns a JSON object of list type (e.g. states.ToList())
so how can i read that object?

states.ToList will have records of ID, and Name,

and I want to bind it with select tag (for selection list at client page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.getJSON(url, null,
  function(data) {
    for (i in data) {
      var state = data[i];
      // do something with state
    }
  }
);
```

If you try this and it does not work, then you are either not returning an array, or you have not specified the names correctly. Look at the Net/XHR panel in Firebug to see the real shape of your data.

Answer (score 0):

Loop! valueArray <= states.ToList()

```
for(var i=0; i<valueArray.length; i++){
  //do something by accessing valueArray[i];
}
```